# Which Visual Studio project settings affect the list of DLLs imported at the start of the program?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

There are two PCs with Visual Studio 2017 installed. I'm running a simple program on both of them, one that lists the name of modules (exes/DLLs) inside its own process.
But I get wildly different results. On one PC, I only get 7 modules:

```
    Lab7_1.exe
    ntdll.dll
    KERNEL32.DLL
    KERNELBASE.dll
    MSVCP140D.dll
    VCRUNTIME140D.dll
    ucrtbased.dll
```

On the other, I get whopping 31 modules. The full list includes, for example, user32.dll, which my sample program isn't using (it's a console app, not a GUI app).

So the question is: *what exactly affects the list of DLLs imported by default?* Debug/Release and x86/x64 switches produces some difference, but nothing that drastic.
Differences between platform tools versions (and corresponding versions of MS VC++ Redist) I can understand, but why are different system DLLs being imported as well?
I'm unsure where else to look.

Context: it's a part of an assignment. On of those PCs is mine, the other is where the students work. The assignment goes like this "We have this set of modules by default, now we use `MessageBoxA()`, and we see that more modules are imported, user32.dll among them". Which doesn't quite work if user32.dll is always imported by default.
Since the behaviour is vastly different, and I can't reproduce it on my PC, it's hard to adapt the assignment so the students can see import mechanics at work.

Sample program code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Psapi.h>
using namespace std;
#pragma comment(lib, "psapi.lib") //needed for MS VS 2010

void EnumerateModules(vector<HMODULE>& modules)
{
    HANDLE me = GetCurrentProcess();
    DWORD needed_size = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        DWORD actual_size = modules.size() * sizeof(HMODULE);
        EnumProcessModules(
            me, //which process
            modules.data(), //where to put the module handlers
            actual_size, //allocated buffer size
            &needed_size //desired buffer size
        );
        if (needed_size != actual_size)
            modules.resize(needed_size / sizeof(HMODULE));
        else
            break;
    }
}

string ModuleName(HMODULE module)
{
    HANDLE me = GetCurrentProcess();
    string buffer(FILENAME_MAX, 0);
    DWORD real_length = GetModuleBaseNameA(
        me, //which process
        module, //which module
        &buffer[0], //where to put the name
        buffer.size() //size of the name buffer
    );
    if (real_length > 0)
        return buffer.substr(0, real_length);
    buffer = "";
    return buffer;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    vector<HMODULE> modules;
    EnumerateModules(modules);
    cout << modules.size() << " modules:" << endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < modules.size(); i++)
    {
        string name = ModuleName(modules[i]);
        cout << name.c_str() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you copy the VS project over to the other PC or did you create a new project there and copied the source files ?

Comment: @nick, I created a new project and copied the text in.

Comment: I tried to dig up some info about the VS default includes, but came up emtpy. Another thought: VS studio solution and project files (*.sln, *vcxproj) are plain text / xml. Maybe throw them into a comparison tool of choice and check for differencens ? (NP++ has a free plugin if you don't have access to one)

Comment: @nick, now that is an interesting idea. I will try and check it.

Comment: Have you tested using the same project (same properties)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, turns out it's not related to Visual Studio settings. I compiled the sample code on one machine, ran in on the other, and got the same result as if I compiled the code there. So it's either Windows version (7 vs 10) or MS VS Redistributable version (though I think both projects used v140). In either case, I can't reproduce the behaviour on my machine unless I'm willing to set up a VM.

Answer (score 0):

> The assignment goes like this "We have this set of modules by default, now we use MessageBoxA(), and we see that more modules are imported, user32.dll among them"

Win32 programs, by default, will import ALL their dependent DLLs up front before any code is executed.  When you invoke `MessageBox` it MIGHT pull in other modules via LoadLibrary, but user32.dll is already loaded before that function is invoked.

The project setting you are wanting is [delay loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls?view=msvc-170) which will generate the behavior you are claiming will happen. That is, the DLL won't effectively be loaded until the function is actually invoked.

Comment: The DLL is imported via LoadLibrary(), though it also can be demonstrated by simply building the program twice - without MessageBoxA() call and with it.
Anyway, the problem is that on some PCs the program imports a whole bunch of DLLs from the get-go, even if it's not calling anything remotely related to them.

Comment: Run `dumpbin /imports` on the binaries to see what dependencies they pull in at runtime.